# How to get mails using Imap for past 1 hours of current date in c#.I am using ActiveUp.Net.Imap4.dll to get mails from gmail

Tags: c#, email, date

Currently I am getting all mail of current date + past 1 hours mail. But I want only past 1 hour mails of current date.

**My code is like this:**

```
mails.SearchParse("SINCE " + DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))



namespace PT.MailIntegration.IMAP
{
    public class MailRepository
    {
        private Imap4Client _client = null;
        public MailRepository(string mailServer, int port, bool ssl, string login, string password)
        {
            if (ssl)
                Client.ConnectSsl(mailServer, port);
            else
                Client.Connect(mailServer, port);
            Client.Login(login, password);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Message> GetAllMails(string mailBox)
        {
            return GetMails(mailBox, "ALL").Cast<Message>();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Message> GetUnreadMails(string mailBox)
        {
            return GetMails(mailBox, "UNSEEN").Cast<Message>();
        }

        protected Imap4Client Client
        {
            get
            {
                if (_client == null)
                    _client = new Imap4Client();
                return _client;
            }
        }

        private MessageCollection GetMails(string mailBox, string searchPhrase)
        {
            Mailbox mails = Client.SelectMailbox(mailBox);
            //MessageCollection messages = mails.SearchParse(searchPhrase);
            MessageCollection messages = mails.SearchParse("SINCE " + DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
            Client.Disconnect();
            return messages;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use code highlighting by indenting your pieces of code. And show a bit more context. We have no idea what your mails object is or where it came from.

Comment: please vote my question if u like so that i can gain reputation